# Quantum Gravity Singularity Question?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-gravity, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, singularities

I am not a expert in QG (Quantum Gravity) or GR (General Relativity) for that matter so please forgive if I make any small mistakes, its just a curious question but I know that a singularity is a point in space or centre of the blackhole, and everything falls into the center so naturally all matter must be at the singularity in order to form a blackhole.

Now since quantum mechanics does say that that we cannot be certain of a particles location without loosing information about its momentum.

1. The problem, is often if I have a particle and I start it at a certain position it follows a certain path towards black-hole (stationary) which can be easily calculated using GR (obviously till the event horizon only), but since we can understand the path we can simply use inverse of the GR equations to figure out the location of the singularity but since we have figured out location of singularity does this not mean the foundation laws  quantum mechanics has been broken as we have located the particles that was part of the blackhole? As we already know the black hole is stationary and now we also know position of it?
2. Similarly how can 2 stationary atoms interact using gravitation (though its small effect) as quantum mechanics forbids knowing exactly where it is, so how can universe "compute" or work like that if QM disallows it?

Comment: 2 things: 1) I haven't checked with everybody else, but I'm sure that nobody would be upset with you for not being an expert in quantum gravity. Those don't really exist yet. 2) the uncertainty on the position of the singularity will come from the uncertainty in the exact positioning of the black hole and that still works with the uncertainty principle since you also will have a non-zero uncertainty with the momentum of the black hole.

Comment: Sole existence of singularity in GR says it breaks there.

Comment: *"a singularity is a point in space"*. No, it really isn't. From https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/144458/123208 "A singularity in GR is like a piece that has been cut out of the manifold. It's not a point or point-set at all".