# General Theory of Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, curvature, singularities

Why is General Theory of Relativity not applicable in the singularity of Black Hole?

Answer (score -2):

The singularity of a Schwarzschild black hole is not part of the manifold but instead a point in time. General Relativity deals with manifolds and thus isn't applicable in the singularity.

You can find more background here:
[Is a singularity a single point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144447/is-a-black-hole-singularity-a-single-point)

> A singularity in GR is like a piece that has been cut out of the manifold. It's not a point or point-set at all.