# Does a Black-hole Represent a Limit To The Value of Energy-density?

Tags: black-holes, string-theory, quantum-gravity, event-horizon, singularities

I've recently read an article that stated the singularity of a black hole could be a string, which is stipulated to be pure energy.

If that's the case, does this mean that the singularity of a black hole could be just pure energy held by gravity? And if that's true, is there a limit to how much energy can occupy the region enclosed by the event horizon?

Comment: A black hole has a very well-defined mass proportional to its radius. Mass is energy. Ergo, it has a well-defined energy content for a given radius.

Comment: What do you mean? The Schwarzschild radius of a non-rotating black hole is proportional to the energy content of the black hole (a rotating BH is a little more complicated).

Comment: What I meant is that the energy takes another form as opposed to quarks, which is string(s). A better formulated version of this question would be -  does energy in form of strings occupy less space than energy in form of matter composed of quarks and above.

Comment: A black hole singularity cannot contain normal matter. We need a quantum gravity theory to say what really happens in the core of a black hole. In the mean time, I recommend you take a look at [Ben Crowell's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/144458/123208) about black hole singularities in standard general relativity.

Comment: @BogdanBulai Assuming classical GR, the radius of a black hole is determined solely by its mass/energy, irrespective of its origin. Also, you may be interested in an entropy bound - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound