Black holes, singularities and topology in relativity
General relativity is defined on a base manifold which, viewed as a topological  space, is simply connected (which means there's no holes). However, we know that inside a black hole there's a singularity, a point of infinite density and curvature.
The way this was explained to me was thinking of it as a literal hole on the fabric of space-time, a point in which nothing is defined.
This, however yields a serious problem.
How is it possible that a theory defined on a simply connected space predicts holes on it? Wouldn't the prediction of holes in a space assumed to be simply connected prove the theory conceptually wrong?

It has not been proven that black holes contain singularities because centrifugal forces resulting from angular momentum would allow particles to travel paths without end.

a black hole is not a "hole", but a place where the curvature scalar diverges. one could still contract a closed curve onto that point, and reach it for a finite value of the parameter chosen for the contraction. also, this question about roy kerr seriously doubting the physicality of a singularity might be of interest to you.

From https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/144458/123208 "A singularity in GR is like a piece that has been cut out of the manifold. It's not a point or point-set at all. Because of this, formal treatments of singularities have to do a lot of nontrivial things to define stuff that would be trivial to define for a point set." Also note that the singularity is never in the past light-cone of any observer, even an observer inside the event horizon.

@PM2Ring That last statement is the essence of the strong cosmic censorship conjecture, which is not yet fully proven (especially for charged black holes).

You are questioning fundamental properties of a theory while making multiple errors.  (1) GR is defined on a metric manifold. It doesn’t have to be simply connected. For example, a flat universe can be a 3-torus, which is not simply connected. (2) Simply connected does not mean no holes per se. Again, in a flat 3-torus, you can connect any 2 points with a straight line without encountering any holes. (3) A singularity is not a point. In the simplest Schwarzschild case it is an infinitely long coordinate line being a moment of time. (4) A singularity has no density, much less infinite density.

@safesphere Can that "unbounded coordinate line" be understood as topological defect like comic string?

@JanG It’s not a topological defect, because this line is present for any planet or star. Let’s use the Earth as an example in polar coordinates. The equation for its center is $r=0$ for any $t$, $\phi$ or $\psi$. This is the equation of an infinitely long line along the $t$ coordinate known as the “worldline”. If the Earth becomes a black hole, this line becomes the line of the Schwarzschild singularity. This line is timelike for the Earth, but spacelike for a black hole, because the space and time coordinates flip at the horizon, but the topology is the same.

@safespace For static spacetime with topology $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2$ it is correct, thanks for your comment. However, if one defines the static spherically symmetric spacetime as sphere bundle over two dimensional Lorentzian manifold (our $\mathbb{R}^2$) your line would be an infinite cylinder with $\mathbb{S}^2$ as cross section. The curvature radius of the cylinder's section would be than $r=0$ for Earth and $r=r_{S}$ for Schwarzschild black hole. Does it sound plausible for you?

@JanG Because the space and time coordinates flip at the horizon, your bundle of static spheres outside continues to the inside as a sphere of the horizon shrinking in time $r$, thus becoming  non-static with the curvature radius also tending to zero. In $R^2 \times S^2$, the coordinates in $R$ are $r$ and $t$. One of them is spacelike, the other is timelike for both the Earth and black hole, inside or outside. Which coordinate is timelike is critical for physics, but irrelevant for topology. The topology still is $R^2 \times S^2$ for all these cases.

@safesphere Space and time switch only if the Schwarzschild exterior solution is extended to the interior spacetime, which I find questionable. A spacetime with perfect fluid sphere consists of an inner and an outer part, each of which is valid only within its domain. For the critical ratio $r_S/R=8/9$ the pressure at the center diverges. The prevailing opinion is that Einstein's theory break up there and the spacetime becomes non-static with the matter collapsing to the singularity.

@safesphere The Gravastar theory proves the opposite. Spacetime beyond the critical ratio remains static. However, because this theory also assumes $R^2\times S^2$ topology there is an interior spacetime with negative energy density. In contrast to it a spacetime with topology of sphere bundle ($R^2\times S^2$ locally) would have no interior. A two-sphere is not contractible to a point as it is the case in a foliation.

@JanG I’ve deleted my last couple comments as misdirected, sorry. Yes, the space and time coordinates flip only in the vacuum  Schwarzschild solution, because it is eternal. My comments above referred to this solution. I agree that this solution does not exist in reality, because the universe is not eternal in the past. The point of my initial comment is not that the theory is perfect, but that the OP cannot hope to find a flaw in it by using severely flawed arguments.

For physical reasons we usually assume that the spacetime manifold is connected, but it is not necessary to assume that it is simply connected. However, simply connected manifolds do have some nice properties that allow certain proofs or theorems which fail in non-simply connected manifolds.
One common class is regarding the existence of geodesics connecting two nearby points, meaning points close enough that the effects of curvature are negligible. In non-simply connected manifolds it is possible that there is no geodesic path connecting two such events because all paths must turn to avoid a small hole.
The Einstein field equations, the core of general relativity, can be well defined on a manifold with a hole. So despite the problems with geodesics, the curvature, the metric, and the stress energy tensor can still work.
However, having said all the above, the Schwarzschild spacetime is simply connected. The singularity in the Schwarzschild spacetime is spacelike, meaning that it is a moment in time, specifically the end of time.
The topology of the Schwarzschild spacetime is $R^2 \times S^2$. Both $R^2$ and $S^2$ are simply connected. So their product is simply connected also.

Even for a simply connected manifold it is not guaranteed that any two points be connected by a geodesic. (E.g. take the submanifold of the euclidean plane described by a (fat) letter C). Additional assumptions/restrictions are required.

@TimRias good point. I will need to revise that part

+1, great answer. For completeness, I would like to add that in GR we usually assume spacetime to be connected (without further adjectives), since we wouldn't have access to other connected components anyway and hence they would be unphysical.

@NíckolasAlves thanks for the suggestion. It is nice to get two good suggestions that actually improve the answer.
