Where is the mass in a Black Hole without a "central" curvature singularity?
Not all black holes have a curvature singularity at their center (an example). But in principle, I thought that the curvature singularity was a direct result of the fact that the mass is concentrated in a non-3D region (like a point, or a ring for a rotating black hole).
So how is it possible to have an infinite 3D-density but not a curvature singularity?
Where with this I mean that the "3D-density" is infinite because the mass is confined in a 2D/1D/0D region.

From https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/144458/123208  "A singularity in GR is like a piece that has been cut out of the manifold. It's not a point or point-set at all."

@safesphere "it is an infinitely long line" in spacetime yes, in space it is a point. "Your question is based on a wrong premise that the mass is located in the singularity." then where is it located? I always assumed it was all at the center.

@PM2Ring I mean isn't it the same thing? A collection of "missing" points is still still a set of points.

@Aleph12345 So, where is the mass of the black hole? Well, it's nowhere. The parameter $M$ in the Schwarzschild metric is interpreted as mass only because at infinity the metric should behave as Newton's gravitational potential of a mass point.
